# What is the authenticity of the hadith about Ja'far's tanned damsel in Paradise?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

> دخلتُ الجنةَ، فإذا جاريةٍ أدماءَ، لعساءَ، فقلتُ : ما هذهِ يا جبريلُ ؟
> فقال : إن الله تعالى عرفَ شهوةَ جعفرِ بنِ أبي طالبٍ للأَدِمَ
> اللَّعِسَ، فخَلَقَ لهُ هذِهِ
>
> Narrated by Abdullah ibn Ja'far in sources:
>
> I entered Paradise and saw a damsel
> with exceedingly tanned skin (Adma) and beautiful dark (red) lips, so
> I asked Jibreel (Gabriel), "Who is this?" And he replied, "Indeed,
> Allaah, The Exalted, knows what Ja‘far ibn Abi Taalib desires, and
> that is tannd skin and dark (red) lips, so Allaah created this for
> him.

I heard it was in Jami' al Saghir 4185 with sources from Tarikh Rafi and Fayd ul Ja'far. However, I was told it was in Mustradak al Hakim.

**Question**: What is the authenticity of this hadith? Is it in the Mustadrak as well?

Answer (score 3):

It was reported in Faydh Al-Qadeer which was a book of interpretation of the ahadeeth of Al-Jaami’ As-Sagheer, which was authored by As-Suyooti.

The hadeeth which you mentioned was reported by As-Suyooti in this book. and he marked it as Da’eef (weak).

Shaykh Al-Albaani classified it as Dha’eef (weak) in Dha’eef Al-Jaami’ As-Sagheer, he pointed out in Silsilatul Al-Ahaadeeth Adh-Dha’eefah wal-Mawdhoo’ah that it had become clear to him that it was a fabricated hadeeth, as he said,

> “Al-Munaawi mentioned the hadeeth in Sharh Faydh Al-Qadeer and in Sharh At-Tayseer, but he did not comment on it; whereas the rule with regard to such a hadeeth is to classify it as Dha’eef. This is what I did in Dha’eef Al-Jaami’ [i.e. I classified it as Dha’eef]. And now, as I came to know about its obscure chain of narrators and pondered about its wording, it has become clear to me that it is a fabricated hadeeth.”

About Mustradak Al Hakim, I couldn't find if the hadith was mentioned in there but if it was, it would be da'eef(weak) anyway as quite a lot of the Mustradak Al Hakim has fabricated hadith as al-Dhahabi said:

> "The Mustadrak contains a good number of hadîth that conform to the conditions of authenticity of both (al-Bukhârî and Muslim) as well as a number of hadîth conforming to the conditions of either one of them. Perhaps the total number of such hadîth comprises half the book. There is roughly another quarter of the hadîth that have authentic chains of transmission, but that have something else about them or that have some defect. As for the rest, and that is about a fourth, they are rejected and spurious narrations that are unauthentic. Some of those are fabrications. I came to know of them when I prepared an abridgement of the Mustadrak and pointed them out."

Comment: Are you saying the hadith above is weak?

Comment: @ZainAlleck   Yes

Comment: @III-AK-III, if you don't mind, could you answer my latest question on a hadith describing people of paradise?

Comment: @III-AK-III, so it is weak then?

Comment: @ZainAlleck — Correct, it is weak as per the answer above.

Comment: @III-AK-III, Ok then, I was wondering, could you answer my other question here: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39818/what-is-the-overall-grade-of-this-hadith-describing-people-of-paradisearabic-u

Comment: @ZainAlleck — I will try my best.

Comment: @III-AK-III, did you see it by the way?

Comment: @III-AK-III, Don't mean to bother you but is it alright?

Comment: @III-AK-III, I was wondering, is the above hadith located in the mustradrak?

Comment: @ZainAlleck — As Armaan mentioned, I could not find it in Al-Mustadrak either. But as Armaan mentioned, not everything in Al-Mustadrak is always authentic. It was about authenticating people, rather than chains being continuous (e.g., what is called _irsal khafi_).

Comment: Oh, so it's still weak then? I think its in volume 3 of the mustradrak page or number 208? Btw(i was wondering, are you an ulema at all?)

Comment: @Armaan, I was wondering,do you speak/read arabic?

Comment: @ZainAlleck   I can read Arabic but I only know what some words mean so when I'm reading Arabic, I don't know what it is saying. Inshallah I will be able to speak fluent Arabic. Some times when I'm readin Arabic, I know some words but I don't know other words so I can't figure out what a sentence translates into.

Comment: I was wondering, do you mind upvoting some questions of mine so I may use the chat? I'd like to discuss with someone on narrators?

Comment: @III-AK-III, Hi, It's been a while. I had a question. Are you a scholar? Yes or No?

Comment: @ZainAlleck — Hi. No, absolutely not. I am not a scholar.

Comment: @ZainAlleck, can you stop commenting on my post for asking personal questions about someone else? It seems like spam.