# What is the overall grade of this hadith describing people of paradise?(Arabic users)

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith

Prophet sallallaahu `alayhi wa sallam ( may Allaah exalt his mention ) who said,

> “The people of Paradise will enter Paradise without any hair on their body, beardless, with a fair complexion and curly hair, having kohl (collyrium) in their eyes, aged thirty-three years, and they will be in the form of Aadam, sixty cubits tall.”
>
> [Ahmad -

and I found some stuff here:

قال الإمام أحمد حدثنا يزيد بن هارون وعفان بن مسلم قالا حدثنا<  حماد بن سلمة عن علي بن زيد بن جدعان عن سعد بن المسيب عن أبي هريرة قال قال رسول الله يدخل أهل الجنة الجنة جردا مردا بيضا جعادا مكحلين أبناء ثلاث وثلاثين وهم على خلق آدم ستون ذراعا في عرض سبعة أذرع 0 قال الإمام ابن القيم رحمه الله :قيل تفرد به حماد عن علي بن زيد 0 أخرجه الإمام أحمد في مسنده 2/295 وابن ابي شيبة في المصنف 7/59 وابن ابي داود في البعث برقم63 وابن ابي الدنيا في صفة الجنة برقم 15 وأخرجه الطبراني في معجمه الصغير برقم 808 وكذلك في الأوسط برقم 5422 وقال: لم يرو هذا الحديث عن علي بن زيد إلا حماد بن سلمة ولايروى عن أبي هريرة إلا بهذا الإسناد0 واخرجه ابو نعيم في صفة الجنة برقم 255 والبيهقي في البعث والنشور برقم 463 ورقم 464 وابن عدي في الكامل 5/198 وقال : وهو مع ضعفه يكتب حديثه0 والحديث رواه جماعة عن حماد بن سلمة عن علي بن زيد بنحوه ومداره على علي بن زيد بن جدعان و هو ضعيف وقد أورد في متنه الفاظ تفرد بها لم يات بها غيره كقوله: في سبع أذرع0 وقد اورد ابن عدي هذا الحديث فيما انكر على اب

وأمَّا حديث علي بن زيد، فيرويه حماد بن سلمة واختُلف عنه: 1- فرواه يزيد بن هارون [مصنف ابن أبي شيبة 34006 ومسند أحمد 7933] 2- وعفان بن مسلم [مسند أحمد 8524] 3- وآدم بن أبي إياس [علل ابن أبي حاتم 2138] 4- وعبيد الله العيشي [المعجم الصغير للطبراني 808 وغيره] 5- وهدبة بن خالد [العظمة لأبي الشيخ 594 وغيره]، عنه، عن علي بن زيد، عن سعيد بن المسيب، عن أبي هريرة، عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم. 6- وخالفهم موسى بن إسماعيل [علل ابن أبي حاتم 2138] 7- ويحيى بن السكن [طبقات ابن سعد 1/15] فقالا: عن حماد، عن علي، عن سعيد، عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم. مرسل ليس فيه أبو هريرة. وحماد يخطئ كثيرًا في روايته عن غير ثابت، وعلي بن زيد لا يحتج به.

إسناده ضعيف ، والحديث حسن لغيره دون قوله " في عرض سبع أذرع ": أخرجه وأحمد في "مسنده" (2/295)، وتابعه ابن أبي شيبة في "المصنف" (7/35) حديث رقم (34006) ، وأبو خيثمة عند ابن أبي الدنيا في "صفة الجنة" (ص/43) حديث رقم (15) ، وتابع يزيد : محمد بن عائشة عند البطراني في "الصغير" (2/75) حديث رقم (808) ، وابن أبي نعيم في "صفة الجنة" (2/99) حديث رقم (255) ، وهدبة عند أبي نعيم في الموضع السابق أيضا وعند أبي الشيخ في "العظمة" (3/1096) حديث رقم (594) ، وتابعه أيضا : عبيد الله العيشي عند أبي الشيخ في الموضع السابق ، مدار الحديث على علي بن زيد بن جدعان ، وهو ضعيف وبه أعل الحديث ابن حجر في "الكافي الشاف" (ص/278) ، وللحديث شواهد ستأتي وأما قوله " في عرض سبع أذرع " قد تفرد بها علي بن زيد ..

= همام بن يحيى، به. ولم يذكر في الموضع الأول الشطر الأول منه. وسيأتي برقم (8295) و (8296) و (10399) . وانظر (9084) . (1) حديث حسن بطرقه وشواهده دونَ قوله: "في عرض سبع أذرع"، فقد تفرد بها علي بن زيد وهو ابن جُدْعان-، وهو ضعيف. وأخرجه ابن

Overall, I don't know what to make of this hadith. Is the above saying some part is authentic and the rest weak?

*edit*: is this saying the narrations support each other @medi1saif:

تخريج الحديث للشيخ شعيب الارناؤوط في مسند أحمد رقم 7933 اقرأ وتعلم

- حَدَّثَنَا يَزِيدُ، أَخْبَرَنَا حَمَّادُ بْنُ سَلَمَةَ، عَنْ عَلِيِّ بْنِ زَيْدٍ، عَنْ سَعِيدِ بْنِ الْمُسَيِّبِ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ، قَالَ: " يَدْخُلُ أَهْلُ الْجَنَّةِ الْجَنَّةَ جُرْدًا، مُرْدًا، بِيضًا، جِعَادًا، مُكَحَّلِينَ، أَبْنَاءَ ثَلَاثٍ وَثَلَاثِينَ، عَلَى خَلْقِ آدَمَ، سِتُّونَ ذِرَاعًا فِي عَرْضِ سَبْعِ أَذْرُعٍ " (1)

  ---

(1) حديث حسن بطرقه وشواهده دونَ قوله: "في عرض سبع أذرع"، فقد تفرد بها علي بن زيد وهو ابن جُدْعان-، وهو ضعيف.
وأخرجه ابن أبي شيبة 13/114، وابن أبي داود في "البعث" (64) من طريق يزيد بن هارون، بهذا الإسناد.
وأخرجه الطبراني في "الصغير" (808) ، وأبو نعيم في "صفة الجنة" (255) ، وابن عدي 5/1842، والبيهقي في "البعث" (419) و (420) من طرق عن حماد، به.
وأخرجه ابن سعد 1/32 من طريق يحيى بن السكن، عن حماد بن سلمة، عن علي بن زيد، عن سعيد، عن النبي صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ مرسلاً.
وسيأتي موصولاً برقم (8524) و (9375) و (10913) ، والموضع الأخير مختصر، وسلف برقم (7165) من طريق أبي صالح عن أبي هريرة مرفوعاً: أن أول زمرة تدخل الجنة على صورة آدم في طول ستين ذراعاً.
وأخرج الدارمي (2828) ، والترمذي (2539) ، وأبو نعيم في "صفة الجنة" (256) من حديث معاذ بن هشام، عن أبية، عن عامر الأحول، عن شهر بن حوشب، عن أبي هريرة قال: قال رسول الله صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ: "أهل الجنة جُرد مُرد كُحل، لا يفنى شبابهم ولا تبلى ثيابهم". وفيه شهر بن حوشب وهو ضعيف، وقال الترمذي: حسن غريب 
وله شاهد من حديث معاذ بن جبل، سيأتي 5/243، وفيه شهر أيضاً.
وآخر من حديث أنس بن مالك أخرجه البخاري في "التاريخ الكبير" 8/219، وابن أبي داود في "البعث" (65) ، والطبراني في "الصغير" (1164) ، وأبو نعيم في "الحلية" 3/56، وفي "صفة الجنة" (255) ، والبيهقي في "البعث" (418) ، وفيه هارون بن رئاب وقد اختلف في سماعه من أنس.
جُرداً مُرداً، قال السندي: الأول جمع أجْرَد: وهو من لا شَعْر على جسده، والثاني جمع أمرد: وهو من لا شعر على ذقنه.
وجعاداً: قال: ضُبط بكسر جيم، جمع جَعْد بفتح فسكون، وفي "المجمع": الجعد في صفات الرجال يكون مدحاً وذماً، فالمدح أن يكون شديد الأسر والخَلْق، أو يكون جعد الشعر، وهو ضدُّ السَّبط، لأن السُّبوطة أكثرها في شعر العجم، والذمّ القصير المتردِّد الخَلْق، وقد يطلق على البخيل، يقال: هو جعد
اليدين، ويجمع على جِعاد.
تنبيه: أورد الحافظان: ابن كثير في "جامع المسانيد" 7/ورقة 174، وابن حجر في "الأطراف" 8/32 لهذا الحديث إسناداً ليس في نسخنا الخطية، وهو: حدثنا عفان، حدثنا حماد بن سلمة، أخبرنا محمد بن زياد، سمعت أبا هريرة عن النبي صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ، وذكره، وقال فيه: "سبعين ذراعاً". 
وهذا إسناد صحي

Comment: This is a exact duplicate of a question from another site: http://www.ummah.com/forum/showthread.php?491688-What-is-the-overall-grade-of-this-hadith-describing-people-of-paradise-(Arabic-users)

Comment: Albaani graded it hasan.

Comment: Note that the quotes are "cut"! Most scholars say that the hadith with the complete content is dai'f, also the narrator chain of this hadith has weaknesses. But there are other ahadith with a similar content which may let the given hadith without a special phrase reach the degree hassan. Note that most other sources of this hadith with the given content are even less reliable than al-Musnad.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Which scholars say it is weak? As well, I was wondering, do the scholars say some part of the hadith is strong and other weak?

Comment: @Armaan. I was wondering, did he say the part without 7 arms length is authentic?

Comment: @Armaan, or did he say the whole thing is weak?

Comment: @Medi1Saif, is what I added in the question at the top saying the narrations is supported by others:

Comment: T Yes if we exclude thee part 7 arms lemgth the hadith finds support in other narrations and may reach the hassan degree. The weak narrator is Ali ibn Zaid ibn Jud'an(?) beside in al-Musnad Hamaad whom reported it from Ali.

Comment: @ZainAlleck      The first hadith you mentioned at the start is hasan.

Comment: @Armaan, Yes though, I was wondering, did al-albni say excluding the 7 arms length part is inauthentic.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, what have scholars said if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Your references are already telling almost everything. Maybe you just don't know how to read them or don't understand the meaning of technical terms. I'm neither in the mood nor having the possibility to answer and explain them. Basically weakness can have two origins a narrator or more in the narrator chain (memory, thrustworthness etc.), or the content itself, either because it is contradicting stronger sources, or not supported by other narrations. i hope that helps.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, I ask because I do not understand arabic. I only used google translate. In this case, does this hadith become hasan.

Comment: @Armaan, can you provide links where it is hasan,please?

Comment: http://m.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=336700

Answer (score 1):

By sorting through the multiple quotes you provided, the quotes basically referenced three versions, where one had one phrase that was *hassan*, and the rest of the version was weak (at best). The other two versions, although they had numerous weak chains of narration, they still had some that were *hassan*.

Almost all of the information was present in your quotes, by the way.

---

### Version 1

> عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ أَنِ النَّبِيِّ ﷺ قَالَ: يَدْخُلُ أَهْلُ الْجَنَّةِ الْجَنَّةَ جُرْدًا مُرْدًا بِيضًا جِعَادًا مُكَحَّلِينَ أَبْنَاءَ ثَلَاثٍ وَثَلَاثِينَ عَلَى خَلْقِ آدَمَ سِتُّونَ ذِرَاعًا فِي عَرْضِ سَبْعِ أَذْرُعٍ
>
> Abu Huraira  narrated that the Prophet ﷺ said: "The people of Paradise will enter Paradise without any hair on their body, beardless, with a fair complexion and curly hair, having collyrium in their eyes, aged thirty-three years; and they will be in the form of Adam, sixty cubits tall, and seven cubits wide."
>
> <sub>— [Sefat Al-Jannah by Abu Na'im 264](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=632&hid=264)</sub>

This version of the hadith was referenced in Jami' at-Tirmidhi (2539), Sunan Al-Darami (2826), Musnad Ahmad (7874, 8319, and 9111), Musannaf Ibn Abi Shaiba (35003), Al-Mu'jam Al-Sagheer (17), Al-Mu'jam Al-Awsat (5422), and Sefat Al-Jannah by Abu Na'im (264). This is not a conclusive list.

There were several chains of narration for this version, that all had the Prophet ﷺ » Abu Huraira » Sa'id ibn Al-Musayyib » 'Ali ibn Zaid » Hammad ibn Salama Al-Basri » others.

Ali ibn Zaid (Arabic: علي بن زيد القرشي), also known as Ibn Abi Malikah (Arabic: ابن أبي مليكة), is [weak](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/RawyDetails.php?RawyID=5770) in hadith, with multiple scholars agreeing not to consider his hadith. For example:

- Ahmad ibn Hanbal said he was weak.
- Ibn Hajar said he was weak, no hadith should be taken from him except when narrated by others, and had bad memory.
- Al-Dhahabi said he used to memorize (i.e., not write), but he had bad memory.
- Yahya ibn Ma'een said he was weak, a nobody, not to be quoted.
- Abu Hatim Al-Razi said he was weak, his hadith could be written but not used as evidence.
- And so on.

All the narrations that had the phrase "and seven cubits wide (Arabic: عَرْضِ سَبْعِ أَذْرُع)" were in a chain that had 'Ali ibn Zaid through Hammad ibn Salama. No one else mentioned this phrase, so this phrase can definitely be discounted as weak.

The only portion of this hadith that is considered hassan is "The people of Paradise will enter Paradise without any hair on their body, beardless, having collyrium in their eyes, aged thirty-three years (Arabic: يَدْخُلُ أَهْلُ الْجَنَّةِ الْجَنَّةَ جُرْدًا مُرْدًا مُكَحَّلِينَ أَبْنَاءَ ثَلاَثِينَ أَوْ ثَلاَثٍ وَثَلاَثِينَ سَنَةًَ)."

**Conclusion**: This version can be considered weak, except for the phrase that is *hassan* because of other narrations (see versions 2 and 3 below).

---

### Version 2

> عَنْ مُعَاذِ بْنِ جَبَلٍ أَنَّ النَّبِيَّ ﷺ قَالَ: يَدْخُلُ أَهْلُ الْجَنَّةِ الْجَنَّةَ جُرْدًا مُرْدًا مُكَحَّلِينَ أَبْنَاءَ ثَلاَثِينَ أَوْ ثَلاَثٍ وَثَلاَثِينَ سَنَةً
>
> Mu'adh bin Jabal narrated that the Prophet ﷺ said: "The people of Paradise shall enter Paradise without body hair, Murd, with Kuhl on their eyes, thirty years of age or thirty-three years."
>
> <sub>— [Jami' at-Tirmidhi 2545](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/727370)</sub>

This version of the hadith was referenced in Jami' at-Tirmidhi (2545), Musnad Ahmad (21600), Al-Mu'jam Al-Kabir (16577), Musnad Al-Shashi (1342), and Sefat Al-Jannah by Abu Na'im (267).  This is not a conclusive list.

There were seven chains of narration for this version, with five of them being *hassan*: The Prophet ﷺ » Mu'adh ibn Jabal » 'Abdul-Rahman ibn Ghanam » Shahr ibn 'Hawshab » Qatada ibn Du'ama » 'Imran Abu Al-'Awwam » Abu Dawud Al-Tayalsi. The reason this chain is only hassan is because of Shahr ibn 'Hawshab (honest, but tends to quote without sanad, and forgets), and 'Imran Abu Al-'Awwam (believed *Al-Khawarij*). All others are fully trusted. These are the reasons why the hadith did not go to the level of *sahih*.

**Conclusion**: This entire version can be considered *hassan*.

---

### Version 3

> عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ أَنِ النَّبِيِّ ﷺ قَالَ: أَهْلُ الْجَنَّةِ شَبَابٌ جُرْدٌ مُرْدٌ مُكَحَّلِينَ لا تَبْلَى ثِيَابُهُمْ وَلا يَفْنَى شَبَابُهُمٌْ
>
> Abu Huraira  narrated that the Prophet ﷺ said: "The people of Paradise are young without any hair on their body, beardless, having collyrium in their eyes, their clothes do not wear out, and their youth does not end."
>
> <sub>— [Sefat Al-Jannah by Abu Na'im 266](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=632&hid=266)</sub>

This version of the hadith was referenced in Sefat Al-Jannah by Abu Na'im (266), with two chains of narration that are both *hassan*, and have the exact same words:

- The Prophet ﷺ » Abu Huraira » Shahr ibn 'Hawshab » 'Amir ibn 'Abdel-Wahid Al-Ahwal » Hisham ibn 'Abdullah » Mu'ath ibn Hisham » 'Ubaidallah ibn 'Umar
- The Prophet ﷺ » Abu Huraira » Shahr ibn 'Hawshab » 'Amir ibn 'Abdel-Wahid Al-Ahwal » Hisham ibn 'Abdullah » Mu'ath ibn Hisham » Hawthara ibn Muhammad

Both chains of narration had Shahr ibn 'Hawshab (honest, but tends to quote without sanad, and forgets), similar to version 2. Also they had 'Amir ibn 'Abdel-Wahid and Mu'ath ibn Hisham, who were both considered *hassan* for hadith. One chain of narration had Hawthara ibn Muhammad, who was also considered *hassan* for hadith. These are the reasons why the hadith did not go to the level of *sahih*.

**Conclusion**: This entire version can be considered *hassan*.

---

### Conclusion

The conclusion is what comes out of the *hassan* hadiths in relation to people of Paradise are:

- Aged 30-33 years
- Their youth does not end.
- Have collyrium on their eyes
- Their clothes do not wear out
- Without body hair.

Comment: I was wondering, are you sure the part about fair complexion and curly hair is considered hasan? I mean, the other narrations/no one else did not mention fair complexion or curly hair though? Here is the original arabic:  يدخل أهل الجنة الجنة جردا، مردا، بيضا، جعادا، مكحلين، أبناء ثلاث وثلاثين. Is the part considered hassan except for curly hair and fair complexion?

Comment: This white complexion and curly hair is only through weak chains, to the best of my research and knowledge.

Comment: But due to the other narrations, is that part considered authentic? You did say it was? Or do you not know? I mean, I read this: (1) حديث حسن بطرقه وشواهده دونَ قوله: "في عرض سبع أذرع"، فقد تفرد بها علي بن زيد وهو ابن جُدْعان-، وهو ضعيف. وأخرجه

Comment: This portion of the seven cubits was narrated only through 'Ali ibn Zaid, and is definitely weak, but that doe not necessarily mean the rest of the hadith is OK. The whole version is weak, but a portion is elevated to hassan based on other narrations and versions of the hadith. Please read the answer.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification, not for argument and debate.

Comment: if you don't mind me asking that is. I don't understand arabic.

Comment: Don't mean to bother you just curious

Comment: @III-AK-III Did. here is the link: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39904/translation-of-this-webpage-that-mentions-hadith-describing-people-of-paradise                              I was wondering, if you are not a scholar of hadith, are you just an ulema/scholar in general though?

Comment: @III-AK-III, in conclusion and to clarify, so for the 7 cubits thing, you are sure it is inauthentic but for the complexion and hair, you're not sure then?

Comment: @III-AK-III, found an answer from hadith scholars: http://hadithanswers.com/another-hadith-on-the-description-of-the-inhabitants-of-jannah/