# What is the authenticity of hadith describing people of paradise with white complexion and curly hair?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith

According to this [website](http://alhodacenter.org/ashora/details.php?id=5240#_ftn31), it mentions the hadith describing people of paradise (curly hair and white) and I was wondering, what does it say about it in this page? Sorry, should've been more specific.

Comment: We are not a translation service. We answer focused question what you are looking for seems to me off-topic see [ask].

Answer (score 3):

The [website](http://alhodacenter.org/ashora/details.php?id=5240) you mentioned in your question is discussing a different topic altogether: Whether Al-Hasan and Al-Hussain are the masters of the youth in Paradise. The website is a Shi'a website, but discussing this hadith from a Sunni perspective, which is a topic both agree on.

The hadith describing people of paradise (curly hair and white) that you are asking about is indeed referenced in this page under [31]. The page partially quotes the hadith in your question [What is the overall grade of this hadith describing people of paradise?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/39858/8393) version 1:

> وقال الألباني في السلسة الصحيحة [حاشية ٣١: جزء ٦ ص ٤٨٦] تعليقاً على ما وصفه بحسنه الترمذي: يدخل أهل الجنةِ الجنةَ جردا مرداً بيضاً جعاداً مكحلين أبناء ثلاث وثلاثين قال: وهو صحيح بمجموع طرقه وشواهده
>
> <sub>*— NOTE: My own translation, so treat with care:*</sub>
>
> [Al-Albani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Nasiruddin_al-Albani) said in *Al-Silsalat Al-Sahiha* [Endnote 31: Vol. 6, pp. 486] commenting on what he described as [Al-Tirmidhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Tirmidhi) said is [hadith] *hassan*: "The people of Paradise will enter Paradise without any hair on their body, beardless, with a fair complexion and curly hair, having collyrium in their eyes, aged thirty-three years." He said it was [hadith] *sahih* through its different versions and evidence.

However, by referring to Al-Albani's said book Vol. 6 (1st Ed. 1996: Riyadh), there is no mention of this hadith on pp. 486. It is mentioned, though, in Vol. 6, pp. 1224, under the notes of Hadith 2987:

> هذا ويشهد لمعنى حديث الترجمة عموم قوله ﷺ: يدخل أهل الجنة الجنة جردا مردا مكحلين بني ثلاث وثلاثين ـ حسنه الترمذي وهو صحيح بمجموع طرقه وشواهده
>
> <sub>*— NOTE: My own translation, so treat with care:*</sub>
>
> And the meaning of the hadith's interpretation his [the Prophet] ﷺ general saying: "The people of Paradise will enter Paradise without any hair on their body, beardless, having collyrium in their eyes, aged thirty-three years."

Again, in the references of the source you provided in your question, there is no mention of "fair complexion and curly hair", same as the answer to your question [What is the overall grade of this hadith describing people of paradise?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/39858/8393).

Comment: @ZainAlleck — Comments of Shuaib Al Arnaout in the line you provided are about the [hadith](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/736500): "Al-Hassan and Al-Hussain are the chiefs of the youth of Paradise."

Comment: @ZainAlleck — It says it is hassan.

Comment: @ZainAlleck — Neither. It says its isnad is hassan because of 'Ali ibn Zaid, and that Ibn Hajar Al-'Asqalani attributed it to Ahmad Ibn Hanbal in Fat'h Al-Bari under Hadith 3326, but that  Ibn Hajar stayed quiet about its authenticity. Ibn Abi-Shaiba said that the hadith was mentioned in his book under the his [does not specify whose, but most likely Ibn Hanbal's] conditions of _hassan_ or _sahih_.

Comment: The footnote is made by Ibn Abi Shaiba, and it does not specify under whose conditions it is hassan, but most likely it is referring to Ahmad ibn Hanbal. It explicitly says Ibn Hajar did not comment on its authenticity. If you would like to continue the discussion, you can use the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3819/jaamiat-stackexchange-al-islamyya).

Comment: I was wondering, in an earlier answer, you said Ibn Hajar said ali ibn zaid is weak. Which Ibn Hajar is it?

Comment: @II-AK-II Is it al haythami or asqalani? Sorry, cannot chat yet

Comment: Don't mean to bother you, but could you kindly answer this last question?

Comment: @ZainAlleck — The reference was to Ibn Hajar Al-Asqalani. But as you mentioned on the other thread that you have confirmed its level with [Hadith Answers](http://hadithanswers.com/another-hadith-on-the-description-of-the-inhabitants-of-jannah/). They have more knowledge about hadith.

Comment: So it was ibn hajar asqalani who said he was weak then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59526/discussion-between-iii-ak-iii-and-zain-alleck).

Comment: I had some request in the chat if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I had a request in chat. Do you mind checking it out?

Comment: BTW, let me know if questions are too much

Comment: III-AK-III this says hasan due to different versions and evidences right:  (1) حديث حسن بطرقه وشواهده دونَ قوله: "في عرض سبع أذرع"، فقد تفرد بها علي بن زيد وهو ابن جُدْعان-، وهو ضعيف. وأخرجه